# Directional Derivatives and the Gradient (Calculus 3)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A shark swimming in water in the presence of blood observes that the concentration of blood in the water is increasing at a rate of 10 parts per million (PPM) per meter when it swims straight up, increasing at a rate of 6PPM per meter when it swims due north, and decreasing at a rate of 5PPM per meter when it swims due east. Assume the change in concentration of blood in the water over time is negligible and consider only the variation in concentration pertaining to spatial position.

a) What direction(s) could the shark swim if it wants the concentration of blood to increase the fastest?
b) What direction(s) could swim if it wants the concentration of blood to decrease the fastest?
c) What direction(s)could it swim if it wants the concentration of blood to stay the same?
d) In part (a) what is the rate of increase?
e) Suppose at the shark's current location, the concentration of blood in the water is 50PPM. Estimate the concentration of blood in the water if the shark swims to a point that is 3 meters west, 2 meters south and 1 meter up from its current location.

So far I have: 
a) north/up 
b) east 
c) i don't know...don't move? 
d) i know we have to find the gradient for this one but I don't know how 
e) I don't know how to estimate 50 PPM on the graph but I know once I get the starting I just move in the direction <3,2,1> and estimate from there?

I'm so confused and need help understanding and working this problem!

Loads of appreciation and thanks!

Comment: Very observant shark...

Comment: The gradient points in the direction of maximum increase and a directional derivative is equal to the dot product of the gradient with unit vectors in the given direction. Given that, are you sure that the direction of maximum increase lies along the axis that points upwards?

Comment: No..so the shark has to swim in the yz plane? so it has to swim up and then north? and for the decrease, it swims east and up?